# Unique record mysql on inserts

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to implement a new system for referal/promotions. my new system where when a user register a specific source is assig to him. A source can be anything from referal (clients domain) and a promotion code (eg: 50% off). This source also have a date (y-m-d). Each source id is unique and multiple users can have the same source id

For example:

```
source id : 1 = www.domain1.com / 2011-11-20 / (empty referal code) 
source id : 2 = www.domain1.com / 2011-11-20 / referalcode1
source id : 3 = www.domain2.com / 2011-11-20 / referalcode1
source id : 4 = www.domain2.com / 2011-11-20 / referalcode2
```

The referal code can be mixed from client1 to client 2

How can i make sure when someone register (its free registration and we have over 1000 per hours now) we dont have duplicate records and risk the mysql to generate errors?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) page:

> The main idea is to insert records using the `ignore` statement. If
>   you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued. Then retrieve the last ID using `mysql_insert_id`

If the record does not exists, it will insert it and the last ID will be returned.

Now, if there's not record returned, you can do your select. This means a record already exists, so simply use it.

*Example:*

```
// make sure $id is safe (preventing sql injections)
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtable SET `field1` = 'value1' ... "; 
mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { // no record found and then the inserts worked
  $id = mysql_insert_id(); // id from the primary key
  // add to cache
}
else {
  // you can also cache them when they were inserted (faster to run than a select statement)
  $id = retreiveFromCache($field1, $field2 /* etc...*/);
  if(!$id) { // no record found in cache
    // now the select can be done using the fields received
    // make sure your use the right index otherwise it can be slow
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM promotions_referrals WHERE `field1` = 'value1' ... "; // 
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    // add to cache
  }
}
```

At this point you will have `$id` assigned and you are sure there's no duplicate/mysql errors.

Note: if a domain belongs to one client, use the client id instead of using the domain. This way you will use INT as index which is faster than VARCHAR. Same idea for referral code.

Comment: so the ignore will not crash mysql and display error like this ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 1?

Comment: yes, that is why you have to catch it with the `mysql_affected_rows()` and make sure it's inserted or not and then process it.

Comment: what about caching? why faster?

Comment: Caching (using memcached, APC or any others) will allow the data to be retrieve from memory instead of actually making a request to the database servers and then process it.

Comment: but the database will always have the data why looking in cache?

Comment: let's say each time you look in the database it takes 1 second (for example) and a lookup in cache takes 0.1 seconds (for example) it is 10x time faster. Therefore, you can have hundreds of requests at the same time without affecting your system.

Comment: At the beginning your table will be small, your script will execute your query fast. But the more your inserts in the database, the worse it can be. If you don't use the index properly, your query can take a long time to execute. read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: ok i made the change to my code and its running now with our test thanks for the info above

Answer (score 0):

You should define your column in MySQL as `INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

When you do inserts, don't specify that column:

```
INSERT INTO referral (domain, date, referralcode) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

If you need the ID you just generated, you can use the function [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)